# Google map ground overlay flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I would like to display an image in overlay at given lat-log positions on `Google map` using `Flutter`. I am using flutter package `google_maps_flutter: 0.5.32`, at present the package does not provide to implement the feature .

Comment: Please share what you have already tried.

Comment: I couldn't implement the feature , I saw the same feature implementation using javascript   in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays.Is it possible to include the feature in flutter

Comment: There is a feature request on `google_maps_flutter` package to support Ground Overlay feature. You can check it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26479

Comment: I found https://github.com/bytestreme/plugins/ this as one of the solution for ground overlaying for android flutter.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I know there is a feature request that is still open for google_maps_flutter but I wanted to see if you found any workarounds?

Comment: @user525429
Please use  github.com/bytestreme/plugins as one of the solution for ground overlaying for android flutter. but there may be other plugin incompatibility issues , implement as per your requirement

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure out a solution to this. I've implemented it in Android at this point, but not for IOS yet.

It was actually fairly simple once I figured it out. But there was a little ground work that needed to occur first.

First, I created a `methodChannel` for my app. In that method channel, I passed an XML string that contains one or more `groundOverlays`. This includes the basics of GPS coordinates, file location of my JPG.

Second, I created a class called `MapOverlays` which is a static class and contains a list of a class called `MapOverlay`. This is just a way for me to actually do multiple overlays at once.

Do this from Android Studio, where you open the Android folder in the Flutter project. You should know how to do this if you've created a `methodChannel` and especially run it for debugging.

These classes were created in:

```
google_maps_flutter/java/io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps
```

Once I've done this, I can receive the XML string via the method channel, and pass that to the constructor for `MapOverlays` which parses the XML code and creates an array of `MapOverlay` items.

Once this groundwork is completed, displaying the overlay on the Google Map when it's created is trivial.

I have to copy/paste the following code into the `GoogleMapController.java` class. It goes at the very end of the method `onMapReady()`.

**SEE FINAL NOTE AT THE BOTTOM!**

```
    ArrayList<MapOverlays.MapOverlay> mapOverlays =  MapOverlays.getMapOverlays();
    
        for (MapOverlays.MapOverlay mo: mapOverlays) {
          if (mo.getVisible()) {
            LatLng southWest = new LatLng(mo.getSouth(), mo.getWest());
            LatLng northEast = new LatLng(mo.getNorth(), mo.getEast());
            LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mo.getImageLocation());
            GroundOverlayOptions mapOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions().image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
            mapOptions.positionFromBounds(bounds);
            mapOptions.bearing(mo.getBearing()*-1);
            mapOptions.transparency(mo.getTransparency());
    
            GroundOverlay groundOverlay = this.googleMap.addGroundOverlay(mapOptions);
          }
      }
```

**Final Note:** I know this is kind of a hack. But I needed this feature and did not want to write my own Flutter Google Map. I looked at a leaflet (`flutter_map` plugin) that looked really promising and implementing an `OverlayImage` item that was trivial once I figured out that's the item that will work. However, `flutter_map` does not support the bearing/rotation. I have many `groundOverlay`s I've created with Google Earth, and they all have some rotation applied. Without this, the maps did not line up on `flutter_map` and I couldn't figure out how to modify the code to take a rotation. So this was a show stopper.

I'm really surprised that `flutter_google_maps` doesn't support the ground overlays. It would be quite trivial to add this support in for Android. I'm hoping that iOS will be as well.

My final comment is that your are modifying Google code that is cached from the Flutter plugin. Anytime you upgrade `flutter_google_maps` (or clear by some other method), you will need to re-apply these changes.

But, for now, I'm able to have a workaround for a desperately needed feature.

I looked for a solution on and off for months. So perhaps this will also help someone else.

Comment: Can you provide a gist of your implementation code?